# Watch the connection status in a camel/netty environment

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I would like to be aware of the connection state in a camel/netty environment.

To do so, I tried something like this:

- *specified my camel route*

```java
    from("direct:in").marshal().serialization()
    .to("netty:tcp://localhost:42123?clientPipelineFactory=#cpf&sync=false");
```

- *implemented my pipeline factory*

```java
    public class ConnectionStatusPipelineFactory extends ClientPipelineFactory {
        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline cp = Channels.pipeline();
            cp.addLast("statusHandler", new ConnectionStatusHandler());
            return cp;
        }

        @Override
        public ClientPipelineFactory createPipelineFactory(NettyProducer producer) {
            return new ConnectionStatusPipelineFactory();
        }
    }
```

- *implemented my connection status handler*

```java
    public class ConnectionStatusHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
        @Override
        public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e)
                throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Event: " + e);
            super.channelConnected(ctx, e);
        }

        @Override
        public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Event: " + e);
            super.channelDisconnected(ctx, e);
        }
    }
```

And finally bound "ConnectionStatusPipelineFactory" to "cpf" in my camel registry.

But the following exception occured:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported message type: class [B
```

*Remarks:*

- "channelConnected" and "channelDisconnected" methods are called as expected.
- When I disable this, everything works (message marshalling, connection, remote process...).

**Questions are:**

- what's wrong with that ?
- is it the good way to know the connection status (connected or not) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the decoder option instead and not the entire client pipeline factory.
eg use option `decoder=#myConnectionStatusHandler`. And then register your ConnectionStatusHandler in the registry with the name myConnectionStatusHandler.

If you use the pipeline factory then you need to add all the others that Camel add out of the box.

Comment: 2 years ! Shame on me... Really sorry ! At the time, I quickly tested your solution but I failed to implement it. So I have done otherwise and forgot to give it another try. It's done today with camel-netty 2.15.2 (not tested on netty4). I still have the following exception _"IllegalArgumentException: unsupported message type: class java.lang.String"_. It looks like I need to "add all the others that Camel add out of the box" too... Not sure if this question will help someone but I hate to didn't answer. Anyway thanks for your help.